# why osmdroid loaded a lot of maps. & Zoom to a wrong place

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am building an app that needs to use OpenStreetMap. The map is loaded. However, when I zoom out I found that there are more than one maps loaded.. in fact, there seems to be infinite numbers of them... One map in the middle, one above and one below; actually if you scroll down the screen, you will see more...

What's the reason? Sorry stackoverflow does not allow me to upload photo. My code is attached and you may wanna try..

Another thing is that, I found my current location latitude and longtitude using location services and stored them in a GeoPoint; then I set the zoom center to that point, but osm went to another point. Very far away.

My code & XML file are attached below

```
public class OsmdActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(10);

    double lat = 1.29377413882149 * 1000000;
    double lon = 103.771969817518 * 1000000;
    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
    mapController.setCenter(p);
}}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gues you have more than on archive (maps) in SD card/osmdroid folder and because of that you see more maps.

For center on your location you can use.

```
    mMapView.getController().animateTo(yourPosition);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but I am not using offline maps. Will that cause this problem?

Comment: Hi thanks I know what my problem is! I should delete that source to use online map..However, for offline use, what do you mean by more than one archive maps?

Comment: I don't think so. Perhaps your internet connection is low or something like this. Or you can check on your sdCard for osmdroid folder and clean it if is not empty.

Comment: When you use online map, osm droid download map cache so second time when you open the app the map is loaded fastest then first time.
As far as I know the osm use SdCard\osmdroid folder to store map cache.
You need map for entire world or only some continent\country\town?

Comment: Really thank you for your help. To your question, I use the map for just one town. Yup, you are correct it's very wasteful.. Well, I considered using offline map but it needs to manually add osmdroid zip file to sdcard?? I need to distribute the app once I am done, my users may not want to add the file manually..Do you have any suggestions for this? Can I put the zip file somewhere in the project and it will be written to users' sd card automatically when installed?

Comment: In my app I also use only one town archive with zoom support from 12 to 16. I use a task for downloading the archive from an external link and copying to sdCard\osmdroid directory. For that you can use AsyncTask example from android.developer.com site and must have permision in manifest.xml file   
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Also for using offline map I recommend you to use this tool [link](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/). Just set on MapSource "OpenStreetMap Mapnik" and create the atlas you want. Put the result in an archive called mapnik.zip and copy to sdCard\osmdroid. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

For me it was that I couldn't set the center when the Activity is created. If I wait for ~200ms before you set the center point, everything works fine.

Here is the ugly fix:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (52.520820* 1E6),(int) (13.409346* 1E6));
            mapView.getController().animateTo(point);
        }
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue regarding centering at a location should have been fixed in osmdroid version 4.3.  The workaround using postDelayed is no longer necessary for version 4.3 onwards.

Details: with the following commit to osmdroid, calls to "animateTo()" etc which previously requires a layout to work correctly would now be recorded and replayed automatically once the layout is created.

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/commit/2f38d49281b31e79a8290d8df55bb738024907e8